# How to trigger an API call on a button click inside an Email Template

Tags: javascript, html

This is a use case where an API has to be triggered when the user clicks a button on his/her email. The API call should hit the server to do some action in backend.
I tried some javascript (fetch, XMLHttpRequest), but also came to know that all email clients do not support javascript. Is it right? Is there any options other than javascript?

Comment: That is not possible, this would be a huge security risk.

Comment: Email clients do not run JS, no. You need to use a link, as in <a> and add GET parameters to supply additional info. Note that if you want to trigger the request automatically when the email is opened, you can add an <img> and use the URL as its `src`. However it is precisely for that reason that many email clients do not load remote images unless you allow it first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most (nearly 99%) of mail clients and servers will put the mail with JS into spam or won't even let it into your inbox. Even the mail client must be able to work with JS. While in Outlook it can be enabled with plugins, you have to be 100% sure, that the receiver will receive it, otherwise you can`t do it.

Another way to fetch data/get mail info like statistics is to add a unique ID to all links used in the mail. By chance, the user will click on it and you can work with the data on server side.

But as allready mentioned: Don`t use JS in your mails. It's not ment for mails.